# jQuery, getting a value with a single class and multiple links

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here's the issue I'm running into. I have a list of names, if a name is clicked on, I need jQuery to pass the variable to another page.

This is what I have, but of course it only pulls the first name.

```
$('.nameLink').live('click', function()  {
    var coachName = $('.coachName').val();
    $('#grayBorder').load('/team.php?coachName='+coachName);                
});
```

And the php code that generates the coaches names:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo '<a class="nameLink">
   <input type="hidden" class="coachName" value="'.$row['coach'].'" />
   '.$row['coach'].'
   </a>';

}
```

Is there anyway to write this so that it will get the correct name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `$('.coachName')` you should have `$('.coachName', this)`

Currently, you are searching the entire page for elements with class `coachName`, but you really only want to find element below the clicked element. By passing the jQuery function a [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) (in your case `this`), you tell it only to search within this scope.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 var coachName = $(this).children('.coachName').val();
```